If I have a positive semidefinite matrix, M, what conditions must U fulfill such that $UMU^{\dagger}$ is also positive semidefnite?
Title basically says it all. The context is that I am simulating the lindbladian master equation of a quantum system, and I am trying to apply some projector $\hat{\Pi}$ to the density matrix to get a renormalised density matrix,
$$\hat{\rho}'=\frac{\hat{\Pi}\hat{\rho}\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}}{\mathrm{Tr}(\hat{\Pi}\hat{\rho}\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger})}$$
I am pretty sure that this should also be positive semidefinite, but my simulations return a matrix with negative eigenvalues. I think this is a numeric thing however I can't think of how to prove that $\hat{\rho}'$ should be positive semidefinite.

I'm sure this already has an answer somewhere on this site. The short answer is yes, because $\langle\xi,UMU^\dagger\xi\rangle=\langle U^\dagger\xi,M(U^\dagger\xi)\rangle\geq 0$ as $M$ is positive semidefinite. I'll leave it as an exercise to you to find an appropriate duplicate target. ;)

Thanks for the help, I think I understand now. Does the condition of $\langle \epsilon,M\epsilon\rangle$ guarantee that M always has positive eigenvalues, or are these separate conditions?
